# OCR multi column text with Google Document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have a document with text in two columns per page. While uploading a test file with this formatting I noticed that the space between the columns was ignored and text was recognized as if it were all a single column page.

The data looks like this:

```
text of  first         text of second
more text test         second test
```

expected output:

```
text of first more text
text of second second test
```

Actual output:

```
text of first text of second
more text test second test
```

I should note: The file was a PDF file in Hebrew. The language was properly recognized and read from right to left as expected.

What can I do about this? Do I need to split it by column or something?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this post about [Correcting text output from Google Document AI](https://bookdown.org/hegghammer/correcting_text_output_from_google_document_ai/reconstructing_text_bookdown_version.html) . The idea is to identify and reorder jumbled text with the tools in the `daiR` package. Suppose your current actual identification and order is 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 from left-right top-bottom, you might have to rearrange it to 1 - 3 - 2 - 4 to get your expected output.

Comment: I agree with the concepts presented in this post, just note that `daiR` is a third-party package and does not have any Google-managed SLA or support.

You can also try creating some custom post-processing for another language by using the text block [Bounding boxes](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#layout) to determine which order they should be loaded in.