# How can I tell Google Document AI Enterprise OCR to always assume one column?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, layout, ocr, text-recognition, cloud-document-ai

How can I tell Google Document AI Enterprise OCR to always assume one column?

My text (scans of old books) are *always* one column.  However, due to layout, (lots of) whitespace, and inline figures, Google Document AI Enterprise OCR sometimes splits the text into two columns.  This causes words to be jumbled out of order:

```
P: The quick brown fox
   jumped over the lazy hen.
```

becomes

```
P1: The quick brown jumped over the
P2: fox lazy hen.
```

Since my text is *always* one column (though the left and right bounds move, due to whitespace, formatting, and inline images), is there a way to tell this to Google Document AI Enterprise OCR?  Or a way to fix it post-OCR?

Comment: Hi @SRobertJames, did you check this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407054/ocr-multi-column-text-with-google-document-ai) ? Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh Thanks.  I saw that link and read the accompanying article, but it is for the opposite problem: How to split columns.  Which they do by rearranging the order.  That won't work for this case, at least as far as I've been able to tell.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP **[support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/)**. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.